# Can I install new flooring over black mastic?

Tags: flooring

I had a flood in my kitchen which has carpet. Under the carpet is a pad, under the pad is black mastic on concrete. Now that everything is dry, I am ready to install new flooring. Should I remove the black mastic or go over it?

Answer (score 0):

If you are installing carpet and using good quality pad, there is no reason to remove that old mastic.

If you are installing vinyl, wood, laminate, or tile then you will probably need to remove it, or at least scrape it down flat, so the new flooring will lie level, even and smooth.